# How to ignore MessageHandlingException while dealing with ProcessBuilder in service-activator

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

That is continuation of the question in [How to integrate legacy executables into Spring Integration application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35366345/how-to-integrate-legacy-executables-into-spring-integration-application)

I asked about incorporating legacy executable files and then incorporated ProcessBuilder.

ProcessBuilder works fine, however I am getting the org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: failed to write Message payload to file.  As I understand, my problem is that for any service-activator I need inbound and outbound channels but in reality I am processing the file information in the executable file prj itself.  What is the best way to avoid this kind of exception?
The configuration file is as follows:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
...
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="producer-file-adapter"
    channel="inboundChannel" directory="file:/Users/anarinsky/springint/chem"
    prevent-duplicates="true">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="5000" />
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:channel id="inboundChannel" />
<int:channel id="outboundChannel" />

<int:service-activator input-channel="inboundChannel"  output-channel="outboundChannel"
expression="new ProcessBuilder('/Users/anarinsky/springint/chem/prj', '/Users/anarinsky/springint/chem/a.dat', '/Users/anarinsky/springint/chem/a.out').start()">
</int:service-activator>
<int-file:outbound-channel-adapter
    channel="outboundChannel" id="consumer-file-adapter"
    directory="file:/Users/anarinsky/springint/chem"/>
</beans>
```

The exception stack starts as follows:

```
19:29:46.236 ERROR [task-scheduler-1][org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler] org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: failed to write Message payload to file
at org.springframework.integration.file.FileWritingMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(FileWritingMessageHandler.java:309)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:170)
at 
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unsupported Message payload type [java.lang.UNIXProcess]
at org.springframework.integration.file.FileWritingMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(FileWritingMessageHandler.java:304)
... 45 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you service invoked by the activator has a `void` return type or returns null, you don't need an output channel. If your service returns a value and you want to discard it, set the `output-channel="nullChannel"` (it's like `/dev/nul` in unix).

Right now, it looks like you are trying to write the result of running the process (a `UnixProcess` to a file). The file outbound adapter doesn't support that payload type (as the exception explains).